# Understanding Concepts

Tags: java, terminology

I am supposed to be writing a java program for a rock paper scissors game. I understand what I am supposed to do however this part confused me.

The implementation involves creating three files. One file contains the client code and the other two files are the classes.
The design for the classes should be:

Class player

Variables: playerName, playerThrow

Methods:
makeThrow-prompts player for the throw

getThrow-returns the players throw

Class Game

Variables: compThrow,playerWins,playerThrow

Methods:

makeCompThrow- generates comp throw

getCompThrow- returns the throw

announceWinner- displays the messages for throws and winner

bigWinner- determine overall winner

I am really confused as to what this means as in what the client code is. Is that like a menu? And how do i get the two classes to work in conjunction with it. Any clarification would be appreciated and please be kind.

Comment: You *really* should talk this over with your professor, a TA, or a tutor.  We can poke, prod and infer from a professional standpoint, but the professor/TA/tutor would have the most intimate knowledge of what the assignment is actually asking.

Comment: My teacher is unavailiable and yet the assignment is due today.  I just dont understand how the two classes are supposed to work with something called a client code

Comment: All I can offer you is professional inference from that point.  If you really want to understand what it is that they're asking you, you should have a conversation with them.  Even if it means your assignment is late, you'll have at least learned a few things from it - one of which being what your confusion is in regards to this assignment.

Comment: I am in an online class so that is very difficult to do. I cant afford to take the late grade on this. Can you please give me your professional inference? I understand what your saying completely and I will talk with him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to comment since I don't have enough reputation.

As Makoto pointed out, only your professor can really tell what needs to be done here. That being said, here's what I think is being asked:

The client code will contain the main function. It will contain the code to call the methods in the classes. For example, it would ask the player to pick one of the three options (rock, paper, scissor) by calling `player.makeThrow()`. Basically, client code is the link between the two classes. That is how the two classes are going to work in conjunction.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. what goes inside the parenthesis

Comment: That would depend on how `makeThrow()` is implemented. The problem statement says that it prompts the player for the throw. So, my guess is that it would just display a menu and take the input from the player. This would require no parameters so nothing would go inside the parenthesis.